# What is the data type of characters ie. "!", "+" in FreeBASIC?

Tags: char, freebasic

I tried char and vargchar, but none of them work. i want to build a calculator and want to ask the user what symbol they want to use like +,-

i tried doing char and vargchar, but none of them work.
using fbide

Comment: You will need to specify which BASIC, as that is a language that has many dialects, each implementation is essentially a different language with some common keywords.  The ANSI standard for BASIC (which no one ha used since about 1980!) has only strings and numbers I recall and no concept if type beyond that

Comment: @Clifford im using the basic that is used by fbide

Comment: You need to include that information in the question, not add it in comments.  Fixed it for you.  Perhaps also include some code to illustrate what you are trying to do that does not work.

Comment: I have no idea where you are getting types chat and vargcharvfrom, they are not FreeBASiC types AFAIK. https://www.freebasic.net/wiki/DocToc

Comment: The IDE you are using is irrelevant. It is FreeBASIC that is critical to answering your question ( and code).

Answer (score 0):

In BASIC (Freebasic/Qbasic/GWbasic) there's no a char type; there's string type! Then you may consider char as it's a string of one byte.

Freebasic sample (also Qbasic):

```
dim x as string

x ="A"
print x
```

Gw-Basic/Qbasic sample:

```
x$ = "A"
print x$
```